# Labeling Species of a Chemical Reaction

Tags: formatting, chemfig

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
{0pt}
{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75} 

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_4}\+\chemfig{Cl_2}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{440\celsius}]}
\chemfig{CH_4}\+\chemfig{CH_3Cl}\+\chemfig{CH_2Cl_2}
\+\chemfig{CHCl_3}\+\chemfig{CCl_4}\
\schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to produce this:

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: `! Undefined control sequence.
\celsius ->\ERROR`. Please add the missing style files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already loading the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package which loads and uses the [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula) package you can use the latter for the reaction.

The key is the `!(<below>)(<text>)` syntax inside of `\ch`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
% \usepackage{siunitx} % already loaded by `chemmacros'

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \ch{
    CH4 + Cl2
    ->[\SI{440}{\celsius}]
    !(\SI{47}{\percent})( CH4 ) +
    !(\SI{20}{\percent})( CH3Cl ) +
    !(\SI{22}{\percent})( CH2Cl2 ) +
    !(\SI{10}{\percent})( CHCl3 ) +
    !(\SI{1}{\percent})( CCl4 )
  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the percent values in the same size as the compounds above you can set the format by changing the option `name-format`. The default setting is `\scriptsize\centering`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
% \usepackage{siunitx} % already loaded by `chemmacros'

\setchemformula{
  name-format= \centering
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \ch{
    CH4 + Cl2
    ->[\SI{440}{\celsius}]
    !(\SI{47}{\percent})( CH4 ) +
    !(\SI{20}{\percent})( CH3Cl ) +
    !(\SI{22}{\percent})( CH2Cl2 ) +
    !(\SI{10}{\percent})( CHCl3 ) +
    !(\SI{1}{\percent})( CCl4 )
  }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for providing another option. I was wondering how I can resize those percentage values and there you are answering it without being asked it's as if you've read my mind thank you. Chemmacros is indeed a very flexible and simplified way doing it. thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\chembelow[<dim>]{<code>}{<stuff>}`. I have used `siunitx`, in addition, to write those percentages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CH_4}}{}
\chemsign{+}
\chemfig{Cl_2}
\arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{\SI{440}{\celsius}}]}
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CH_4}}{\SI{47}{\percent}}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CH_3Cl}}{\SI{20}{\percent}}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CH_2Cl_2}}{\SI{22}{\percent}}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CHCl_3}}{\SI{10}{\percent}}
\chemsign{+}
\chembelow[1.5ex]{\chemfig{CCl_4}}{\SI{1}{\percent}}
\chemsign{+}
\chemfig{HCl}
\schemestop
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you've saved my life again. This is my second question that you answered..

Comment: Out of interest: why do you prefer `\chemsign{+}` instead of `\+`? I don't see any arguments for or against it?

Comment: @cgnieder It is more semantic, readable (when you write big (long) reactions). And `chemfig` manual consistently uses it. I have a slight doubt that the OP is mixing commands from different packages.  Also it gives better spacing.

Comment: @HarishKumar that's because a) `\chemsign` was there from the beginning and b) `\+` was/is defined to be used between `\schemestart ... \schemestop` (and only defined between them) and has been introduced with v1.0. And since the manual's examples haven't been changed... `\chemsign` might be more semantic but `\+` has in general more options for adjustment and thus is more flexibel.

Comment: @HarishKumar I use `chemfig` a *lot* :)